# Replace string if it matches part of another string

Tags: r, regex, string, text, replace

I have a column of people's last names and their initials, in some instances a person may be listed twice, once with a single initial (e.g. SMITH C) and once with two initials (e.g. SMITH CD), I want to replace all instances of SMITH CD with SMITH C.

An example

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:7,
  names = c("JOHN S", "JOHN SW", "JOHNSON S",
            "SMITH C", "SMITH WC", "SMITH CD",
            "HANK K"))
> df
  id     names
1  1    JOHN S
2  2   JOHN SW
3  3 JOHNSON S
4  4   SMITH C
5  5  SMITH WC
6  6  SMITH CD
7  7    HANK K
```

I can do this manually for a single name e.g.:

```
df$names <- gsub("SMITH CD", "SMITH C", df$names)

> df
  id     names
1  1    JOHN S
2  2   JOHN SW
3  3 JOHNSON S
4  4   SMITH C
5  5  SMITH WC
6  6   SMITH C
7  7    HANK K
```

But my real dataset contains ~4000 names, therefore I want to be able to:

1. programmatically identify cases where last names and the first initial match, and
2. make all the replacements in one go

For the small example df above the result would be:

```
> df
  id     names
1  1    JOHN S
2  2    JOHN S
3  3 JOHNSON S
4  4   SMITH C
5  5  SMITH WC
6  6   SMITH C
7  7    HANK K
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a grouping column by removing the letter at the end when there are two letter words, then modify the `names` by selecting the element having the minimum number of characters

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    group_by(grp = str_remove(names, "(?<= [A-Z])[A-Z]$")) %>% 
    mutate(names = names[which.min(nchar(names))]) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
#     id names    
#  <int> <chr>    
#1     1 JOHN S   
#2     2 JOHN S   
#3     3 JOHNSON S
#4     4 SMITH C  
#5     5 SMITH WC 
#6     6 SMITH C  
#7     7 HANK K
```